# Why htmlentities would wreck query?

Tags: php, sql

I have this simple php script:

```
    // $_POST["sql"] = "INSERT INTO ..."
$pol = @new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);    
    if(isset($_POST["sql"])){
            $sql = $_POST["sql"];
            $sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($pol, htmlentities($sql, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
            echo $sql;
            $result = $pol->query($sql);
            echo $result;
        }
```

For some reason it doesn't work unless I remove the line with htmlentities function. Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Don't escape the full query string, just the values. But a better option is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: There's also no reason to use `htmlentities()` on query data. That should *only* be used when displaying data on a web page.

Comment: htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // Will only convert double quotes (not single quotes), and uses the character-set Western European.
Please make sure whether it's useful or not for you.